# using chrome developer, how can I source the audio file from a clip on a website?

Tags: file, google-chrome, audio, save

there are a handful of instances where I need to source the audio file playing on a website - often from a 'test' button. for ex: a sound clip of someone pronouncing a word in a foreign language, test exports of a file that was edited, etc.

is there a go to area in the dev tools, ie memory, sources, console, etc.

right click save as doesn't work. depending on the site, I can 'inspect' the test button and find the link in the elements/html code but not always